# Is there a secure implementation of inheritable Withdrawable/Withdrawal Pattern contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I'm building a contract which allows users to pay, earn and withdraw ether.

I want to keep it modular, so I want to write a contract named "Withdrawable".
The core contract will then inherit it and get a complete deposit/withdrawal system from it.

I searched for a while but didn't find what I want.
Most of the contracts just put anything together in one contract.

So I made a very simple one by myself.
It's not perfect, but it may help you get the idea.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

/// @title BasicWithdrawable
/// @author Roger Wu (https://github.com/roger-wu)
/// @dev A cheap and not so secure implementation of a withdrawable contract.
/// @dev Inherit this contract to enable withdrawal from a contract.
contract BasicWithdrawable {
  using SafeMath for uint;

  mapping (address => uint) private balances;

  /// public getters

  function balanceOf(address _user) public view returns(uint _balance) {
    return balances[_user];
  }

  /// public functions

  function() public payable {
    deposit();
  }

  function deposit() public payable {
    _increaseBalance(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public {
    require(_amount <= balances[msg.sender]);

    _decreaseBalance(msg.sender, _amount);
    _increaseBalance(_to, _amount);
  }

  function withdrawAll() public {
    require(balances[msg.sender] > 0);

    /// @dev To avoid re-entrancy attack, update the balance before transfer.
    uint _amount = balances[msg.sender];
    _decreaseBalance(msg.sender, _amount);
    msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
  }

  function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    require(_amount <= balances[msg.sender]);

    _decreaseBalance(msg.sender, _amount);
    msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
  }

  /// internal functions

  /// @dev This function should be called when the derived contract gets paid
  ///   and wants to update the balance of a user.
  function depositTo(address _user, uint _amount) internal {
    require(_user != address(0));
    _increaseBalance(_user, _amount);
  }

  /// private functions

  function _increaseBalance(address _user, uint _amount) private {
    balances[_user] = balances[_user].add(_amount);
  }

  function _decreaseBalance(address _user, uint _amount) private {
    balances[_user] = balances[_user].sub(_amount);
  }
}
```

This contract is not secure enough because there is no contraint on depositTo() method.
If the derived contract does something wrong and causes
the sum of balances != this.balance, we have no way to prevent or fix it.

Is there a more secure and well-audited implementation of this contract?

Comment: Just a heads up. You have a problem in your `public payable` fallback function because you are not doing any accounting for funds received. You need to `balances[msg.sender].add(msg.value);` You "should" be able to do that and to emit an event and stay within the 2,300 gas stipend. I would add event emitters to the state-changing functions.

Comment: Writing to storage costs more than 2300 gas (but exceeding that is okay).